# instantiating and defining classes in python

Tags: python, class

There is a python file named `BasePlat.py` which contain something like this:

```
class BasePlatform(SimObj):
  type = 'BasePlatform'
  size = Param.Int(100, "Number of entries")

class Type1(BasePlatform):
  type = 'Type1'
  cxx_class = 'Type1'
```

Now this file is used in another file named `BaseModel.py`

```
from BasePlat import BasePlatform
class BaseModel(ModelObj):
  type = 'BaseModel'
  delay = Param.Int(50, "delay")
  platform = Param.BasePlatform(NULL, "platform")
```

These file define the parameters. In another file `inst.py`, some models are instantiated and I can modify the parameters. For example I can define two models with different delays.

```
class ModelNumber1(BaseModel):
  delay = 10

class ModelNumber2(BaseModel):
  delay = 15
```

However I don't know how can I reach `size` parameter in `BasePlatform`. I want something like this (this is not a true code):

```
class ModelNumber1(BaseModel):
  delay = 10
  platform = Type1
  **platform.size = 5**

class ModelNumber2(BaseModel):
  delay = 15
  platform = Type1
  **platform.size = 8**
```

How can I do that?

Comment: [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) would like you to rename `BasePlat.py` and `BaseModel.py` to `baseplat.py` and `basemodel.py`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The attributes you are defining are at class level, which means that every instance of that class will share the same objects (which are instantiated at definition time).

If you want `ModelNumber1` and `ModelNumber2` to have different `platform` instances, you have to override their definition. Something like this:

```
class ModelNumber1(BaseModel):
  delay = 10
  platform = Param.Type1(NULL, "platform", size=5)

class ModelNumber2(BaseModel):
  delay = 15
  platform = Param.Type1(NULL, "platform", size=8)
```

Edit the `BasePlatform` class definition with something like this:

```
class BasePlatform(SimObj):
  type = 'BasePlatform'
  size = Param.Int(100, "Number of entries")

  def __init__(self, size=None):
    if size:
      self.size = size
      # or, if size is an integer:
      # self.size = Param.Int(size, "Number of entries")
```

If you don't have access to the `BasePlatform` definition, you can still subclass it as `MyOwnBasePlatform` and customize the `__init__` method.

Comment: it says TypeError: extra unknown kwargs {'size': 8}

Comment: well, you have to change the definition of the `__init__` method of `BasePlatform`, allowing it to accept the `size` parameter...

Comment: hard task since I didn't write that... I will try.